# I'm using Single Page Application, how do i toggle between divs in one function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, toggle, single-page-application

Four of five divs have the class Hidden on them. And when i push a button, i only want two of them to toggle the class Hidden. How can i do that?? Is it possible??

Right now, everything inside function toggling is toggled.

I have tried to take the variables and put them in to the callback function i use. So i only want to toggle the profile and login variable in the if statement.
Please help me.

```
if (response.status == 200) {
        let data = await response.json()
        window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.token)
        window.localStorage.setItem("userId", data.userId)
        toggling()
        secured()
        writeProfileInfo(data.user)
    } else {
        console.log("HANDLE ERROR ON LOGIN")
    }


function toggling() {
    let profile = document.querySelector(".Profile__Wrappe")
    let updateProfile = document.querySelector(".Update-Profile")
    let reg = document.querySelector(".Reg__Wrapper")
    let login = document.querySelector(".Log__Wrapper")
    let match = document.querySelector(".Match__Games")
    profile.classList.toggle("Hidden")
    updateProfile.classList.toggle("Hidden")
    reg.classList.toggle("Hidden")
    login.classList.toggle("Hidden")
    match.classList.toggle("Hidden")
}

    let profileUpdateBtn = document.querySelector(".Profile-Button__Update")
profileUpdateBtn.addEventListener("click", async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: What is the issue? Can you make a [mcve]  - click edit and then `[<>]`

Comment: The issue is that everything inside function toggling is toggled.